# Sharing Single SQLite database across multiple android apps.

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

If the user has my android app installed in his device (of database size 300mb), How can i make all my other apps or thirdparty apps to freely access the database. ContentProvider may be a solution, but i am still in development stage so don't exactly who or how many third-party apps will leverage my database in-order to prespecify shared user id's in AndroidManifest.xml

If not SQLite is there any alternative android supporting DB supporting the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) Its better to use sqlite for one device.

But you are asking for sharing one database for multiple device. so use `Network Connection` and check [Connecting to remote database](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Comment: No i am not asking about sharing across "Multiple devices", my concern is just about "multiple apps within a device". ContentProvider has a mandate of requiring shared user id in-order give access to thirdparty apps, so i am looking for option that gives more freedom to thirdparty apps to read my sqlite without any id's or other mandates.